# How to reuse code block which describe similiar ant build logic in groovy?

Tags: groovy, ant, gradle

How to reuse code block which describe similiar ant build logic in groovy?

If we have build logic which was implemented by Groovy AntBuilder, just like code below:

```
ant.someTask(attr1:value1, attr2:value2) {
    configuration1(param1:args1, param2:args2){
        similiarStructure(additionalArgs:aaa){
            setting1(param5:value5) {
                //...blah blah blah
            }
            //further more settings, may be or may be not the same with similiarStructure below
        }
    }

    configuration2(param3:args3, param4:args4){
        similiarStructure(additionalArgs:aaa){
            setting1(param5:value5) {
                //...blah blah blah
            }
            //further more settings, may be or may be not the same with similiarStructure below
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any ways to reuse Groovy AntBuilder code block, which could brief the statment in configuration2 ? 
I've try to predefine closures and inject them in both configuration, 
but it fails with property not found exception while initializing closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll provide two answers so you can select which one is more appropriate for your use case and test it. The solutions depend on at what level you want the shared config.

If you want a more general purpose solution that allows you to share the whole of the `similarStructure` block, you need to perform some more advanced work. The trick is to ensure that the *delegate* of the shared configuration closure is set appropriately:

```
def sharedConfig = {
    similarStructure(additionalArgs:aaa) {
        setting1(param5:value5) {
            //...blah blah blah
        }
    }
}

ant.someTask(attr1: value1, attr2: value2) {
    configuration1(param1:args1, param2:args2){
        applySharedConfig(delegate, sharedConfig)
    }

    configuration2(param3:args3, param4:args4){
        applySharedConfig(delegate, sharedConfig)
    }
}

void applySharedConfig(builder, config) {
    def c = config.clone()
    c.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    c.delegate = builder
    c.call()
}
```

Although the `applySharedConfig()` method seems ugly, it can be used to share multiple configurations across different tasks.

One thing to bear in mind with this solution is that the `resolveStrategy` of the closure can be very important. I think both `DELEGATE_FIRST` and `OWNER_FIRST` (the default) will work fine here. If you run into what appear to be name resolution problems (missing methods or properties) you should try switching the resolution strategy.

Comment: I prefer this one. It teaches me how to reuse groovy closures. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide two answers so you can select which one is more appropriate for your use case and test it. The solutions depend on at what level you want the shared config.

If you are happy to simply share the closure that goes with `similarStructure`, then the solution is straightforward:

```
def sharedConfig = {
    setting1(param5:value5) {
        //...blah blah blah
    }
}

ant.someTask(attr1: value1, attr2: value2) {
    configuration1(param1:args1, param2:args2) {
        similarStructure(additionalArgs:aaa, sharedConfig)
    }

    configuration2(param3:args3, param4:args4) {
        similarStructure(additionalArgs:aaa, sharedConfig)
    }
}
```

The method that is `similarStructure` should ensure that the `sharedConfig` closure is properly configured. I haven't tested this, so I'm not entirely sure. The disadvantage of this approach is that you have to duplicate the `similarStructure` call with its arguments.